# rdebug-ide passing ruby args along with ruby script

Tags: ruby, arguments, bundle, vscode-debugger

I need to pass additional args along with rdebug-ide with bundle exec, something like this.

```
$bundle exec rdebug-ide <ruby program>.rb <ruby program argument>

$bundle exec rdebug-ide myprog.rb --myprog-initialize-args
```

rdebug-ide returns invalid option

```
--myprog-initialize-args
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?